# FineUploader 3.1: german special-character

Tags: php, utf-8, fine-uploader

fine-uploader 3.1 jquery-Version works fine until filename starts with a German special character (äöü). I think this is browser- and OS-independent. HTML and PHP is set to UTF-8.

Uploading a file named "äöü test.txt" I get "test.txt" on [Server]/tmp. A file named "Xäöü text.txt" will be transferred correctly.

How can I fix this?

---

I think there is nothing strange on client-side. Maybe I'm wrong:

```
$('#dlgVorgangNewUpload').fineUploader({
  request: { endpoint: '././Objekt.ajax.php' }, 
  button: null,
  text: { uploadButton: txt,
    cancelButton: 'Abbruch',
    failUpload:  "Upload fehlgeschlagen"    
},
  multiple: true,
  retry: { showButton: false },
  validation: {sizeLimit: 10485760 }, // 10 x 1024 x 1024
  debug: true
}).on('submit', function(event, id, filename) {
    UploadCounter++;
    $(this).fineUploader('setParams', {'todo': 'VorgangUpload'});
}).on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON ){
    UploadCounter--;
    if (responseJSON.success) {
      if (UploadCounter == 0) BusyShow("importiere Dateien....");
      $.ajax({
    // some stuff to store file-inbformation in Database
        ...
      });
    } else if (responseJSON['error']){
      msgbox (responseJSON['error'],"Fehler:");
    }
}).on('cancel', function(event, id, filename) {
     UploadCounter--;
});
```

This is the output from Firebug:

```
Parameter:
  qqfile    äöüß test.doc
  todo  VorgangUpload

Header:
POST /incl/Objekt.ajax.php?todo=VorgangUpload&qqfile=%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%9F+test.doc HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.de
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-File-Name: %C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC%C3%9F%20test.doc
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
X-Mime-Type: application/msword
Referer: https://xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.de/incl/Objekt.php?id=4190
Content-Length: 12800
Cookie: .....
PHPSESSID=.....
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

---

hmmm.

within Shell:

```
file -i Objekt.ajax.php
Objekt.ajax.php: text/x-php; charset=utf-8

echo $LANG    
de_DE
```

php-file:

```
...
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
...
```

What else should I do? I don't understand why this should be a server issue. Transfering a file with special chars works **fine** until a filename **starts** with a special char. This is very strange to me.

Comment: The issue is likely with your server code or server environment.  You'll need to reveal more information about your server, along with your server code.  Fine Uploader is not a factor here.

Comment: Make sure your PHP script is saved with a UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Very strange. I don't deal with PHP and special characters much. You are not doing anything strange on the client-side? Fine Uploader is *not* transform the file's name or encoding in any way.

Comment: i've found it myself: php/basename() struggles if locales are not set. setlocale (LC_ALL, 'de_DE'); is the solution.

solved